How would you interpret feedback that you are "too good"
How would you interpret the following feedback and how can I find out what stands behind it? I am a tech lead to the project and there is a newly assigned team lead. We were having some agile coaching session and we were supposed to give feedback to different people. So my team lead gave me the following feedback:

I am very technically good. I am actually too good.
I have many balls in the air

It really strikes me how can anyone be "too good" for what he is doing. How would you interpret such feedback, and how can I approach him and ask what he meant by I am "too good"? Any suggestions? The feedback was given in front of a lot of people. Somehow I did not feel very flattered really.

You should ask them, not us.

Reading minds is above your pay grade. It's above mine too.

It sounds like you try to be the master of everything, are likely not wholly successful in that attempt, and are trying to juggle too many balls at once.

I am not going to add to the answers, but management behavior is the answer. It will be one of 3 actions. 1.) Compliment if you get advancement or more money. 2.) BS - if Nothing happens. 3.) An excuse to demote if they want to lessen costs or move you out. Thoughtful managers really shouldn't use phrases like "you're too good". It just isn't direct and honest (IMHO).

I would interpret this as a chance to renegotiate my work contract and ask for a raise.


how can I aproach him and ask what the hell does he mean that I am
"too good"

Something like "Hey, [team lead]. During our Agile coaching session, you said I was too good technically. I was confused by that. Can you help me out tell me more about what you meant?" should work.
When you want to understand what someone meant when they said something, ask the person who said it.

You approach him and ask by approaching him, and asking him.
"Hey, I've been thinking about it and I'm not sure what you meant by 'too good'. Do you mean I am trying too hard and overcomplicating things, or taking on too much at once, or assuming things are obvious and under-commenting or not writing enough error messages,... Or that if it was up to you, you would promote me to a higher rank and/or give me a more challenging assignment?"
Don't assume it was criticism until you know. Also, don't assume it was praise until you know. When something isn't clear at work, ask. Better to ask and be thought a fool than to guess wrong and remove all doubt. And phrased this way, which shows that you have been trying to resolve the problem yourself, it isn't even a foolish question.

ok, but I would not make suggestions myself, e.g. "did you mean this" or "did you mean this". It overcomplicates the question, gives too much information and might bias the person unconsciously. Just plain and simple "what did you mean"? If you get a stupid answer like, "it's obvious", you can still elaborate.

@SybillePeters: I think it's helpful to show why the statement could be confusing, but I see your point too.


I am very technically good. I am actually too good.

This is referred to as a "backhanded compliment" - something that sounds like a compliment, but contains or hints at something that is not complimentary at all, perhaps even an insult.
This is typically a passive-aggressive approach to criticism. When interviewing candidates for a job, sometimes "you are overqualified" is feedback that justifies not hiring someone.
Someone saying this, especially someone qualified or given the authority to assess you, is essentially saying that there is a gap between what is expected of you and what you are doing / how you are responding to those around you.

I have many balls in the air

This simply means that you lack focus in that person's mind. You are handling too many responsibilities at the same time to the point where it impacts others negatively. This usually happens when someone can't say "no" when asked or when someone feels like others will not do as good a job. This leads to incomplete work, missed deadlines and/or prevents others from helping.
Taken together, this person is trying to tell you that you need to "lead" more and "do" less. A lead is supposed to help other team members learn and grow on their job, in addition to providing feedback to them to help them accomplish that. Additionally, you are expected to take on more challenging tasks if others cannot. Then help them see what you did so they can learn from your experience/insights.

how can I approach him and ask what he meant by I am "too good"?

Approach him by saying, "I would like to be a better lead. It sounds like you think I have the right technical skills, but maybe I need to do things differently to help my team. What can I do differently that you think would help?"
The first part, acknowledging that you want to be better than you are can help frame the conversation that you are willing to listen and change. If you aren't, then don't say it. The second part, acknowledging that you have technical skills but leveraging them to a fault, including by overextending yourself can also help pave the way for a productive conversation. Again, if you think you are doing things right already, then skip it.
That last part is really the key thing. You received criticism in the form of a backhanded compliment and a vague assessment of inferior task management. You need to know what to do different in your job in order to remove the criticism / negative implications of the feedback.

The manner in which I've heard this phrase used before in a negative connotation is that there is no notion of the deliberation of the work or consideration of the team in completing tasks and solving problems.
Deliberation of work
In the deliberation of work, problems that are too easily solved by you do not benefit the team. We've seen in school the notion of "show your work" on a math test, and this is really no different. If a problem is very easy for you, you may not be leaving enough context for your team to be able to understand the solution or maintain it long term.
Additionally, the solution that is trivial to you may be non-trivial to the rest of the team. What good is it if you're producing code that is functional and performant if the resulting code is too complex or involved for the team to follow? I've known several people who have coded brilliant solutions to complex problems, and in the context of working within a team they were horrendous. The team itself suffered because of these "free electrons".
Consideration of the team
That second piece bleeds into the notion of considering the team. It puts forth code and solutions that the team is simply not prepared or capable to support, maintain, or follow. This creates code with multiple patterns and practices embedded in it which is very disjointed and hard for any programmer to follow. If something that is tightly coupled suddenly begins using a complex dependency injection for an object and then back to tight coupling, the usefulness of the DI is gone, and all that remains is a convoluted code base.
Suppose the team is performing. They're meeting their deadlines, they're producing good SOLID code, and they're delivering according to benchmarks. "Too good" would be you're exceeding these benchmarks in a manner that is not replicable by the rest of the team. Are you making yourself look good or are you making them look bad? Are you putting a sign on yourself by such performance to indicate "I'm not a team player" by standing out in such a way?
My recommendation would be to get to the heart of the feedback to find out which it is, and either way, it's a good opportunity to evaluate your own performance against how you operate within the team. Are you educating them, supporting them, working to make sure their coding capabilities are in line with what you're producing? When you solve something in a complex or rapid manner are you providing them with guidance to help them do things faster or more efficiently?
As a tech lead, I would say your paired responsibilities are equally code production and team performance. How is being "too good" negatively impacting the members of your team? It might be that it's highlighting their deficiencies. Shrugging that off as "not my problem" (which is very common in developers/engineers) is the distinction between a "senior" and a "lead". A lead cares about the team and does everything they can to make sure the team members are supported and functioning optimal. A senior isn't required to care. They're just there to pump out high level code. (note: this is not my definition of a senior, and it is still how seniors are largely regarding in the FAANG sector)

Vernacularly speaking, being "too good" is often used as a compliment.  As in, "I can't believe you are pulling all of this off, you are too good!"  I have used similar phraseology with my own subordinates and colleagues.
But, we have no way of knowing what was meant by your Team Lead.  I would suggest an informal meeting with said lead and ask him if he could clarify his statements and inquire directly if he has any concerns about your performance.


How would you interpret such feedback

Generally with inconsequential remarks that have no ongoing affect you just discount them rather than get a swelled head or create drama over them. So if it was me I wouldn't bother interpreting it at all. It's not clear what the meaning was supposed to be, and it's not clearly negative, so it's just noise.
My only interpretation would be an observation that my team lead does not make clear statements, which might be indicative of weaknesses if it's a pattern going forwards.

I think this is a fair piece of advice if you are secure of your job position and you have a strong self-belief and understanding of your worth in the company. However, it might be the OP suffers from insecurity or has some foreboding, however irrational,  that jobs will be slashed in which case telling someone to ignore or shrug off their suspicions will not help.

@Mari-LouA I disagree, you either look for an agenda or pattern behind things that don't make sense, or feed your insecurities obsessing over noise. I'm not saying the OP should forget it, just discount it as meaningless until a pattern emerges. You don't confront people over trifles like this, how will that end well? If it's negative they'll make up an excuse or pretend they can't remember, how would you know which?

If you know your worth, and if your contributions are valued across the board   and appreciated by all, then there's nothing else to do but... if your doubts and second guessing is affecting your performance the next best thing to do is to ask for (not confront your supervisor) clarification. I'm guessing the OP belongs to the latter.

@Mari-LouA it's a confrontation, you'd look like you're either fishing for a compliment or you think your colleague talks gibberish you can't understand. Look at it from both sides. The time to ask for clarification has long passed.

Hi, thanks for meeting up with me. I know this is a really busy period for everyone but this should only take a few minutes. Well, erm... cut to the chase, you know that feedback you gave XX days ago? I've been thinking about it, and I'm not really sure what you meant by me being too good? Should I be reading something between the lines or should I take it as a genuine appreciation of my work?

@Mari-LouA yep, if it's negative it brings it into focus, if it's positive it looks like compliment fishing. Either way unnecessary and accomplishes nothing.

Partially agree. The "too many balls in the air" is however pretty clear feedback and he could reflect a bit on that to see if his focus, his priorities and delegation and mentoring skills need improvement.
